# Trying to understand multi threading in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Help me understand multi threading using the below example. The GUI freezes once I click the submit button. How to call a threading function?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text='vicks')
label.pack()

def fix():
    a=0
    for i in range(0,1000000000000000):
        a=i
    label['text']=a

button = tk.Button(text='sub', command=fix)
button.pack()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox()
dropdown.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)

Comment: import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text='vinoth')
label.pack()

def fix():
    a=0
    b = threading.Thread(target=count, args=(a,))
    b.start()

def count(a):
        for i in range(0,10000000):
            a=i
        label['text'] = a

button = tk.Button(text='sub', command=fix)
button.pack()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox()
dropdown.pack()

root.mainloop()




This should work! Call a function from the button, that could trigger a thread (which in turn will call another function to do your job)

Comment: Thanks, that works great.