# How to make matplotlib animate in a while loop in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to live plot EEG recording in my tkinter app. However, it does not plot while the data is updating in the while loop, and plots only at the end.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Button, LabelFrame, N, W, messagebox as box

import time
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class NFB_HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.nfbprotocol = 0
        self.metricstime = 0
        self.nfbmetric = 0
        self.df = []
        self.xList = []
        self.yList = []

        # Start Neurofeedback
        self.StartNFB = Button(self, text="Start NFB", width=25, command=self.onStartNFB)
        self.StartNFB.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=W)

        # LabelFrame for EEG Graph
        labelframe3 = LabelFrame(self, text="EEG Plot")
        labelframe3.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=2, sticky=N, rowspan=5, columnspan=4)

        self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, labelframe3)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=W)

    def createDF(self):
        df_timestamp = []
        df_data = np.empty([0, 5])

        # metrics
        df_alpha = np.empty([0, 1])
        df_beta = np.empty([0, 1])
        df_theta = np.empty([0, 1])
        df_delta = np.empty([0, 1])
        df_alpha_theta = np.empty([0, 1])
        df_metricstime = np.empty([0, 1])

        return df_timestamp, df_data, df_alpha, df_beta, df_theta, df_delta, df_alpha_theta, df_metricstime


    def onStartNFB(self):
        try:
            self.start()
            # Initialize dataframes
            df_timestamp, df_data, df_alpha, df_beta, df_theta, df_delta, df_alpha_theta, df_metricstime = self.createDF()

            # Start recording here!
            timestart = time.time()

            while time.time() < timestart + int(4):
                """ 3.1 ACQUIRE DATA """
                self.metricstime = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')

                """ 3.3 COMPUTE NEUROFEEDBACK METRICS """
                alpha_metric, beta_metric, theta_metric, delta_metric, alphatheta_metric = float(np.random.normal(size=1)), float(np.random.normal(size=1)), \
                                                                                           float(np.random.normal(size=1)), float(np.random.normal(size=1)), \
                                                                                           float(np.random.normal(size=1))
                self.nfbmetric = alpha_metric

                # Save the bands to data frame
                df_alpha = np.append(df_alpha, [[alpha_metric]], axis=0)
                df_beta = np.append(df_beta, [[beta_metric]], axis=0)
                df_theta = np.append(df_theta, [[theta_metric]], axis=0)
                df_delta = np.append(df_delta, [[delta_metric]], axis=0)
                df_alpha_theta = np.append(df_alpha_theta, [[alphatheta_metric]], axis=0)
                df_metricstime = np.append(df_metricstime, [[self.metricstime]], axis=0)

                # Update graph
                self.df = np.concatenate([df_metricstime, df_alpha, df_theta, df_alpha_theta],
                                         axis=1)
                print(self.nfbmetric)

        except:
            raise RuntimeError("Error with Neurofeedback.")


    def start(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=int(500))
        self.running = True
        self.ani._start()


    def animate(self,i):
        df = self.df
        for eachline in df:
            if len(eachline) > 1:
                dfX = eachline[0]
                dfY = eachline[1]

                self.xList.append(dfX)
                self.yList.append(dfY)

        self.ax1.clear()
        self.ax1.plot(self.xList, self.yList)
        title = "Neurofeedback Band Power"
        self.ax1.set_title(title)

app = ExpGUI()
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.mainloop()
```

Does somebody know what is wrong with my code? I know how to get it to run outside the while loop, but I have problems getting it to run while the data is updating.

Comment: `while`-loop blocks `mainloop()` which redraws window and all widgets. You can use `app.update()` to force  `mainloop` to redraw window. Or use `app.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to run function periodically (without `while`-loop) and not block `mainloop()`.

Comment: Read [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)