# How to run a function from a button based GUI window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a menu driven program that has GUI capability. For the sake of this post I edited it down so the menu has 2 options, to quit and to calculate an average of a set of numbers. I ran this before I used the GUI code and it worked perfectly.

The issue is that when I click "Average", it runs the function and allows 1 input but then I can't enter another number. Same issue with other functions I had. They won't run past the first input and then the Quit button also won't quit.

Feel free to ask any questions in the comments if I wasn't good at describing what I needed. It's my first day using GUI so sorry if anything looks weird, I'm trying to teach myself but got stuck here. End goal is to have the whole program run in a GUI environment but I figured starting with the menu would be the best place to start.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def average():
    print("Enter test scores to get the average of. Type '-99' to quit.")
    num = 1
    count = 0
    total = 0
    while num != -99:
        num = int(input("Enter numbers: "))
        total += num
        count += 1

    average = (total + 99) / (count-1)
    print("The average is: ", average)

    print("-----------")
    main()

def main():

    r = tk.Tk() 

    r.title('Number games')
    button1 = tk.Button(r, activebackground = "blue", bg = "light blue", text='Average', width=25, command= average)
    button4 = tk.Button(r, activebackground = "blue", bg = "light blue", text='Quit', width=25, command=r.destroy)

    button1.pack()
    button4.pack()

    r.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: You could run that same loop in the terminal. Not sure it's a tkinter issue... Most GUI apps would open an input box, not require to input somewhere else outside that GUI

Comment: Suggest you read [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time)

Comment: `import *` is not prefered - see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: The code you posted does not cause the problems you describe when I run it. It lets me enter multiple numbers, gives me the average, and the buttons remain responsive. I was going to say "you need to put the console input in its own thread", but for some reason I don't understand, your code seems to work fine as is. Of course, running `main()` from the end of `average()` repeats the same thing as when it is first run.

Comment: your code works for me too. Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7.5. But maybe problem is only on some systems. For example PyGame on Windows has problem when it doesn't get events from system and in your program `mainloop()` is geting events from system but you `while` loop is blocking `mainloop` so it can't run. If you have long-running code then you should rather run it in separated thread.

Comment: frankly, GUI which uses `input()` instead of `tk.Entry()` to get value looks very weird.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759), [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759) and your error [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `main()` from inside `average()`.  When I delete that line, your program works exactly as expected for me (debian 9, python3).

Ps. Don't use `import *`.

Answer (score 0):

Globalize the variable `r` and declare `r.destroy()` in another function above main function. Note `from tkinter import *` is enough no need to import tkinter again with an alias.