# Pass varibel from another Py file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-import

So i am trying to make a GUI using tkinter, that should read files from some other microcontollers. 
to do this i have made a Uart.py which i am pretty sure is working as it should. and then i try to pass its "work" over to another py file where i have my GUI in. but i cant get that part to work, where i am importing from the Uart.py

my Uart.py Code

```
import serial
import time

data = ""
dataTemp = "b'temperature temp read \r\n'"
dataPh = "b'ph probe read \r\n'"
value = ""
#dataWater = "b'ph dispenser write ' +str(int(waterAmount.get())1000).encode('ascii') + b' \r\n'"


class uart(object):
    uart = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', baudrate=9600)

    def write(self, data):
        self.uart.write(data.encode())
        print("sent")
        time.sleep(3)

    def read(self, value):
        while True:
            self.value = self.uart.readline()
            time.sleep(2)
            print(self.value)
            value = self.value
            self.uart.flush()
            return value


if __name__ == '__main__':
     while True:

        def tempUart():
            myTemp = uart()
            myTemp.write(data=dataTemp)
            myTemp.read(value)

        def phUart():
            myPh = uart()
            myPh.write(data=dataPh)
            myPh.read(value)

 #      def waterUart():
 #           water = uart()
 #           water.write(data=dataWater)
```

And this is my Main Program GUI.py where i am importing it to and setting the value for ph by calling def phUart

```
import sys
from Uart import *
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *

PhSet = Uart.phUart()
tempSet = Uart.tempUart()

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.attributes('-fullscreen', 'True')


        self.ph = Label(fg="black", background="#D6D7D6",text = "Ph: ",font=("Helvetica", 40, "bold"))
        self.ph.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.temp = Label(fg="black", background="#D6D7D6",text = "Temp: ",font=("Helvetica", 40, "bold"))
        self.temp.grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.klor = Label(fg="black", background="#D6D7D6", text="Klortabletter tilbage: ", font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
        self.klor.grid(column=8,row=8)
 #       self.waterAmount = Spinbox(from_=1000,to=100000,increment=1000,width=10, font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
 #       self.waterAmount.grid(column=0, row=6)
 #       self.waterButtonSet = Button(text = 'Set water amount',command = set_waterAmount,font=("Helvetica",10,"bold"))
 #       self.waterButtonSet.grid(column=0,row=6)

        phSet = dataPh
        self.phSet = Label(width=5, fg="black", background="#D6D7D6", textvariable=dataPh, font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
        self.phSet.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.tempSet = Label(width=5, fg="black", background="#D6D7D6", textvariable=ph, font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
        self.tempSet = grid(column=1, row=4)

        ## KLOR ##


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = gui()
    gui.tk.mainloop()
```

i have just started to program in python so i am not even sure if this is posible.

Comment: Read [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)

Comment: Thanks but i dont think it helps much, cant seem to find the solution in there. my problem is that i want to get the def from Uart.py and use its varibel in GUI.py so i can use the Uart.py to read and write and just the other file as my GUI. for eks. updating phSet it should call the uart to get information and then set it in from that one?

Comment: How can you be sure that `uart.py` *works* when it doesn't do anything? You have a `while` loop, but nothing executes in it.

Comment: @quamrana i have testet it on the raspberry before i tried to put it into the GUI.

Comment: @stovfl oh okay, so is not posible to do what i am trying to do?

Comment: @MadsVestergaard ***"is not posible to do what i am trying to do"***: It is possible, you have to change your module `uart.py` by moving the `__main__` part into your `class uart:`

Comment: Okay I tried to do what I think you meant down in the new code, but now I can't get the variable?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that `Uart.py` is running its main method. If you want to use Uart as a custom module, then you don't want `Uart.py` to run the `__main__` loop. Instead, `Uart.py` should look something like:

```
import serial
import time

data = ""
dataTemp = "b'temperature temp read \r\n'"
dataPh = "b'ph probe read \r\n'"
value = ""
#dataWater = "b'ph dispenser write ' +str(int(waterAmount.get())1000).encode('ascii') + b' \r\n'"


class uart(object):
    uart = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', baudrate=9600)

    def write(self, data):
        self.uart.write(data.encode())
        print("sent")
        time.sleep(3)

    def read(self, value):
        while True:
            self.value = self.uart.readline()
            time.sleep(2)
            print(self.value)
            value = self.value
            self.uart.flush()
            return value
```

Then, when using your `uart()` object in `GUI.py`, you would use it like so:

```
import sys
from Uart import *
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    from tkinter import *

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.phSet = uart()
        self.phSet.write(dataPh)
        self.tempSet = uart()
        self.tempSet.write(dataTemp)
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.attributes('-fullscreen', 'True')


        self.ph = Label(fg="black", background="#D6D7D6",text = "Ph: ",font=("Helvetica", 40, "bold"))
        self.ph.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.temp = Label(fg="black", background="#D6D7D6",text = "Temp: ",font=("Helvetica", 40, "bold"))
        self.temp.grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.klor = Label(fg="black", background="#D6D7D6", text="Klortabletter tilbage: ", font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
        self.klor.grid(column=8,row=8)
 #       self.waterAmount = Spinbox(from_=1000,to=100000,increment=1000,width=10, font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
 #       self.waterAmount.grid(column=0, row=6)
 #       self.waterButtonSet = Button(text = 'Set water amount',command = set_waterAmount,font=("Helvetica",10,"bold"))
 #       self.waterButtonSet.grid(column=0,row=6)

        self.phSet = Label(width=5, fg="black", background="#D6D7D6", textvariable=dataPh, font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
        self.phSet.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.tempSet = Label(width=5, fg="black", background="#D6D7D6", textvariable=ph, font=("Helvetica", 20,"bold"))
        self.tempSet = grid(column=1, row=4)

        ## KLOR ##
```

Notice a few changes made here:

1. Since you use `import * from Uart`, you don't need to specify `Uart.uart()` when instantiating a new `uart()` object. This means we can just declare `phSet` in the `gui` object's constructor with `self.phSet = uart()`. The same holds true for `tempSet`.
2. Removed the `phSet = phData` line from `GUI.py`. This is because, using the syntax from your version of `Uart.py`, it looks like you use the `write()` function to write the phData to the phSet. You can do this in the constructor for the `gui()` object as I have done in the above code.
3. As an extension of the previous point, there is no reason to specify `data=foo` when passing arguments to the `write()` function. The `data` parameter does not need keyword arguments. [Read more about default arguments and keyword arguments here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/)

I apologize if I misunderstand the purpose of your code, and have implemented incorrect 'fixes.' I think what you are getting at and what you need is just using custom modules in Python, and there are tons of ways you can implement this. I purposely left out re-writing a `__main__` function for you, because you can do that either in `GUI.py` or you can write a new `app.py` or something of the likes to run your `__main__` function, and that gives you more control over adding functions and classes to custom modules that you write elsewhere.

Hope this helps!