# Can't stop a while with Tkinter buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have two buttons **Start** and **Stop** and when I click on the start button, I want to go through a while, but when I want to stop it, the Tkinter window is blocked and I can't click on the **Stop button** because the whole window is blocked.

Below is my code:

```
s = 1
def Start():
   while(s==1):
      #do something
def Stop():
   global s
   s = 0

btn_Start= Button(root, text = 'Start',width=9, height=2, command = Start).place(x=2,y=2)
btn_Stop = Button(root, text = 'Stop',width=9, height=2, command = Stop).place(x=2,y=42)
```

Does anyone know how can I stop the while?

Edited:--------
still the same error

[image]

Comment: Read [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the function simultaneously with active window, you have to connect it with threading method.

The threading method creates a thread which creates a separate execution of your program.

Here's Your Solution,

```
import tkinter
import threading
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

s = 1

def Start():
    while(s==1):
        print(s)
        #do something


def thread():
    global t
    t = threading.Thread(target = Start)
    t.start()

def Stop():
   global s
   s = 0
   t.join()
   print("Stopped")

btn_Start= Button(root, text = 'Start',width=9, height=2, command = thread).place(x=2,y=2)
btn_Stop = Button(root, text = 'Stop',width=9, height=2, command = Stop).place(x=2,y=42)
```

In above program the `Start()` is assigned as thread.Hence, when `Start` button is pressed the commanded `thread()` will create a new thread by executing `Start()` function.
When `Stop()` function will called, `t.join()` will include that thread to your `Stop()` function execution.

Here you can find threading module documentation,
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading

Comment: It didn't work. I have added a photo in my question to see what happens. Can you have a look, please?

Comment: My fault, I forgot to change the command for btn_start. It's working

Comment: One more problem, the while is not stopping. I think it didn't take the same 's'

Comment: The 's' is defined as global variable.So, when each function is called it uses assigned value of 's'.If while loop doesn't stop, you can use boolean variables and if else condition inside a while loop