# tkinter placing a continuous while loop function inside

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, calculator, text-widget

I am trying to build a simple calculator. I want insert a calculation inside the `t1` text box. For example if `t2` text box and `t3` text box is filled or change `t3` text box would automatically do the calculation. **How can I make my `t1` text box have a while loop that continuously calculates the value in the other two boxes?**

Here's my code, if anything is confusing please let me know! Thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as TkFont

root = tk.Tk()
#helv36 = TkFont.Font(family="courier new",size=10,weight="bold")

#e1 = tk.Text(root, bg='black', fg='white', font=helv36)
#e1.pack()
#row=0, column=0, rowspan=0, columnspan=0




def open_pl():
    pl = tk.Toplevel()
    pl.title('P/L')
    pl.geometry('305x255')


    #label
    l1 = tk.Label(pl, text='Profit/Loss Calculator', padx=90, pady=4).grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2)
    l2 = tk.Label(pl, text='Initial Balance: ',justify='left', anchor='w').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
    l3 = tk.Label(pl, text='Balance: ',justify='left', anchor='w').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
    l4 = tk.Label(pl, text='thinkorswim: ********', padx=85, pady=4).grid(row=5, column=0,columnspan=2)

    #text box
    t1 = tk.Text(pl, height=2, width=20, padx=70, pady=15)
    t2 = tk.Text(pl, height=2, width=20, padx=20).grid(row=2, column=1,columnspan=4)
    t3 = tk.Text(pl, height=2, width=20, padx=20).grid(row=3, column=1,columnspan=4)
    t4 = tk.Text(pl, height=2, width=20, padx=70, pady=15).grid(row=4, column=0,columnspan=2)


    t1.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=2)

    # i tried it here
    while t3 != 0:
        initial_balance = t2.get('1.0', INSERT)
        balance = t3.get('1.0', INSERT)
        t1.insert('1.0', (float(balance)-float(initial_balance))/float(initial_balance))





menubar = tk.Menu(root)
m1 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
m1.add_command(label="P/L", command=open_pl)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=m1)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: You should use `Entry` instead of `Text`.

Comment: You can put the calculation logic in a function, and then bind the function to `<KeyRelease>` event on `t2` and `t3`.

Comment: ***" have a while loop that continuously ..."***: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759) and [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)

Comment: dam soooo helpful !