# In a Tkinter program, how can I prevent widget behavior from lagging if it is placed in a time consuming function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI program such that when a button is pressed, a label should be shown that indicates some processed has started, and the process should then start. I placed all of that inside a function that gets called when the button is pressed. This causes the label to not show up right away. I think this is because the Tkinter window works in loops and the whole function must finish executing before any change is reflected in the window, is that correct? What is a good way around this?

```
import time
from tkinter import *

def function1():
    myLabel = Label(root, text="process started...").grid(row=6, column=3)
    time.sleep(3)
    #or some time consuming process...
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

button = Button (root, text="trial", command=function1)
button.grid(row=7, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759), [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application) and/or [how to use after method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multithreading, [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module, to run something on a different thread. If you run it on a different thread, the Tkinter window won't wait for the whole function to finish, since that function is being run in a different thread then the Tkinter window.

1. Import the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module

```py
import threading
```

2. Create a function you want the new thread to run
3. Create a new thread and pass in the function you created

```py
thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=arguments)
```

Where `target` is the function you want to call in this new tread, and `args` are the arguments you need to pass into your function (you can leave `args` out if there are no arguments to pass in)

4. Run the new thread

```py
thread.start()
```

---

Editing anything in the `Tk()` object must be done in the same thread it was created in (basically you can't edit anything in the same window, in 2 different threads).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add `root.update()` right after the `Label` (before the function).

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

def function1():
    myLabel = Label(root, text="process started...").grid(row=6, column=3)
    root.update()  # So it will display the Label right now 
    time.sleep(3)
    # Or some time consuming process...
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

button = Button (root, text="trial", command=function1)
button.grid(row=7, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

This will update the window, so you will see that `Label` right away.